# Programmatically solving a system of nonlinear equations over GF(2)

Tags: finite-fields, math-software, sagemath, magma-cas

I have the following relatively large system of nonlinear equations over $GF(2)$:

$
0 = w_7x_7 + w_7x_5 + w_7x_4 + w_7x_0 + w_6x_6 + w_6x_5 + w_6x_1 + w_5x_7 + w_5x_6 + w_5x_2 + w_4x_7 + w_4x_3 + w_3x_4 + w_2x_5 + w_1x_6 + w_0x_7 \\
0 = w_7x_6 + w_7x_4 + w_7x_3 + w_6x_7 + w_6x_5 + w_6x_4 + w_6x_0 + w_5x_6 + w_5x_5 + w_5x_1 + w_4x_7 + w_4x_6 + w_4x_2 + w_3x_7 + w_3x_3 + w_2x_4 + w_1x_5 + w_0x_6 \\
0 = w_7x_5 + w_7x_3 + w_7x_2 + w_6x_6 + w_6x_4 + w_6x_3 + w_5x_7 + w_5x_5 + w_5x_4 + w_5x_0 + w_4x_6 + w_4x_5 + w_4x_1 + w_3x_7 + w_3x_7 + w_3x_6 + w_3x_2 + w_2x_7 + w_2x_3 + w_1x_4 + w_0x_5 \\
0 = w_7x_7 + w_7x_4 + w_7x_2 + w_7x_1 + w_6x_5 + w_6x_3 + w_6x_2 + w_5x_6 + w_5x_4 + w_5x_3 + w_5x_3 + w_4x_7 + w_4x_5 + w_4x_4 + w_4x_0 + w_3x_6 + w_3x_5 + w_3x_1 + w_2x_7 + w_2x_6 + w_2x_2 + w_1x_7 + w_1x_3 + w_0x_4 \\
0 = w_7x_7 + w_7x_6 + w_7x_5 + w_7x_4 + w_7x_3 + w_7x_1 + w_6x_7 + w_6x_6 + w_6x_5 + w_6x_4 + w_6x_2 + w_5x_7 + w_5x_6 + w_5x_5 + w_5x_3 + w_4x_7 + w_4x_6 + w_4x_4 + w_3x_7 + w_3x_5 + w_3x_0 + w_2x_6 + w_1x_7 + w_1x_2 + w_0x_3 \\
0 = w_7x_6 + w_7x_3 + w_7x_2 + w_6x_7 + w_6x_4 + w_6x_3 + w_5x_5 + w_5x_4 + w_4x_6 + w_4x_5 + w_3x_7 + w_3x_6 + w_2x_7 + w_2x_0 + w_1x_1 + w_0x_2 \\
0 = w_7x_7 + w_7x_5 + w_7x_2 + w_7x_1 + w_6x_6 + w_6x_3 + w_6x_2 + w_5x_7 + w_5x_4 + w_5x_3 + w_4x_5 + w_4x_4 + w_3x_6 + w_3x_5 + w_2x_7 + w_2x_6 + w_1x_7 + w_1x_0 + w_0x_1 \\
1 = w_7x_6 + w_7x_5 + w_7x_1 + w_6x_7 + w_6x_6 + w_6x_2 + w_5x_7 + w_5x_3 + w_4x_4 + w_3x_5 + w_2x_6 + w_1x_7 + w_0x_0 \\
$

I would like to solve the system for the 8 $w$ variables in terms of $x$. I know Sage and Magma implement relatively new techniques for converting this system to its CNF equivalent and then solving using popular SAT solvers like Minisat, but such techniques do not allow one to "fix" (for lack of a better word) variables (i.e. they solve the solve for exact values of $w0\dots w7$ and $x0 \dots x7$).

Does anyone know how I can accomplish this task using a CAS? The system above is really only a small example; I have larger systems with more variables whose equations have more monomials, so doing this task by hand becomes very time consuming.

Comment: I'm a bit curious about the origin of the system. If there are shortcuts, they would depend on the structure of the underlying problem. As observed by Hurkyl, the system is linear in the $w$s, so e.g. Gaussian elimination works, but you get a possibly messy denominator coming from the determinant of the coefficient matrix.

Comment: It's actually equivalent to computing the multiplicative inverse in $GF(2^8)$. That is, for $x = (x0,\dots,x7)$ and $w = (w0,\dots,w7)$, we have that $wx = 1$ or $(0,0,0,0,0,0,1)$. More details are described in section 5.2 of this book: http://www.springer.com/computer/security+and+cryptology/book/978-0-387-24363-4

Comment: Well, I suspected that much :-). I would use a look-up-table and/or discrete logarithm table in that case. Is that not an option for you? Will your hardware not allow you to set aside a few hundred bytes of memory for this purpose?

Comment: It's not that we can't use look-up-tables, it's that we're trying to create minimized combinational circuits for such computations (i.e. those with a minimal number of logic - XOR and AND - gates).

Comment: Ok. Sorry, I forgot that you already asked about this in another question.

Comment: No need to apologize. I appreciate your interest and very quick responses. :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In general you could use Groebner basis methods, but it turns out that your system is much easier: it's ***linear*** in $w$.

(although you may still want to solve it using Groebner basis methods even though it's linear so as to easily keep things reduced modulo the relations like $x_7^2 + x_7$)